# Char into byte? (Java)

Tags: java, char, byte, int, primitive-types

How come this happens:

```
char a = '\uffff'; //Highest value that char can take - 65535
byte b = (byte)a; //Casting a 16-bit value into 8-bit data type...! Isn't data lost here?
char c = (char)b; //Let's get the value back
int d = (int)c;
System.out.println(d); //65535... how?
```

Basically, I saw that a `char` is 16-bit. Therefore, if you cast it into a `byte`, how come no data is lost? (Value is the same after casting into an int)

Thanks in advance for answering this little ignorant question of mine. :P

EDIT: Woah, found out that my original output actually did as expected, but I just updated the code above. Basically, a character is cast into a byte and then cast back into a char, and its original, 2-byte value is retained. How does this happen?

Comment: Yeah, just realized that it does so on mine as well. I updated the code above, though, and now, basically, a character is cast into a byte and then cast back into a char, and its original, 2-byte value is retained. How does this happen?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As trojanfoe states, your confusion on the results of your code is partly due to sign-extension.  I'll try to add a more detailed explanation that may help with your confusion.

```
char a = '\uffff';
byte b = (byte)a;  // b = 0xFF
```

As you noted, this DOES result in the loss of information.  This is considered a [narrowing conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).  Converting a char to a byte "simply discards all but the n lowest order bits".
The result is:  `0xFFFF -> 0xFF`

```
char c = (char)b;  // c = 0xFFFF
```

Converting a byte to a char is considered a [special conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4).  It actually performs TWO conversions.  First, the byte is SIGN-extended (the new high order bits are copied from the old sign bit) to an int (a normal widening conversion).  Second, the int is converted to a char with a narrowing conversion.
The result is:  `0xFF -> 0xFFFFFFFF -> 0xFFFF`

```
int d = (int)c;  // d = 0x0000FFFF
```

Converting a char to an int is considered a [widening conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).  When a char type is widened to an integral type, it is ZERO-extended (the new high order bits are set to 0).
The result is:  `0xFFFF -> 0x0000FFFF`.  When printed, this will give you 65535.

The three links I provided are the official Java Language Specification details on primitive type conversions.  I HIGHLY recommend you take a look.  They are not terribly verbose (and in this case relatively straightforward).  It details exactly what java will do behind the scenes with type conversions.  This is a common area of misunderstanding for many developers.  Post a comment if you are still confused with any step.

Answer (score 8):

It's [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Try `\u1234` instead of `\uffff` and see what happens.

Answer (score 7):

java `byte` is signed. it's counter intuitive. in almost all situations where a byte is used, programmers would want an unsigned byte instead. it's extremely likely a bug if a byte is cast to int directly.

This does the intended conversion correctly in almost all programs:

```
int c = 0xff & b ;
```

Empirically, the choice of signed byte is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Some rather strange stuff going on your machine. Take a look at [Java language specification, chapter 4.2.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1):

> The values of the integral types are
>   integers in the following ranges:
>
> For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive

... snip others...

If your JVM is standards compliant, then your output should be `-1`.