# Byte and char conversion in Java

Tags: java, encoding, unicode, utf-16

If I convert a  character to `byte` and then back to `char`, that character mysteriously disappears and becomes something else. How is this possible?

This is the code:

```
char a = 'È';       // line 1       
byte b = (byte)a;   // line 2       
char c = (char)b;   // line 3
System.out.println((char)c + " " + (int)c);
```

Until line 2 everything is fine:

- In line 1 I could print "a" in the console and it would show "È".
- In line 2 I could print "b" in the console and it would show -56, that is 200 because byte is signed. And 200 is "È". So it's still fine.

But what's wrong in line 3? "c" becomes something else and the program prints `?  65480`. That's something completely different.

What I should write in line 3 in order to get the correct result?

Comment: A `byte` is `8 bit`.  `char` is `16 bit`. Got the idea?

Comment: @RohitJain And a character — by which I mean a Unicode code point — can take two chars or four bytes. Furthermore, who knows what normalization form things are in?  The string `"È"` can itself comprise one or two code points depending on whether it is in Normalization Form C or D respectively.

Comment: Two bytes for `char` vs one for `byte` is a problem in the general case, but here, on its own, that wouldn't matter as 'È' is a codepoint below 256, so could be stored in one byte. Problem here is that `char` is unsigned while `byte` isn't. Casting `char` to `byte` only works for ASCII, so not for codepoints above 127, like here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Char into byte? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958658/char-into-byte-java)

Answer (score 86):

TL;DR: The byte value `0xC8` is a negative value which gets widened to a negative integer, and then narrowed back again to a positive character with value `0xFFC8`. Use `char c = (char) (b & 0xFF)` so that the intermediate integer value remains a positive `0x000000C8`.

### What happens

#### Short explanation

A character in Java is a Unicode code-unit which is treated as an unsigned number. The Java char is  is basically [UTF-16BE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description), which maps character `È` to value `0x00C8`. Once this is narrowed down to a byte containing `0xC8` it represents the value -56. When casting to char the value is first widened to the integer representation of -56: `0xFFFFFFC8`. This in turn is then narrowed down to `0xFFC8` when casting to a `char` which translates to the positive number 65480. This then gets widened to an integer during your `println` statement to `0x0000FFC8` to represent the same value.

#### The JLS

The Java Language Specification documents:

[5.1.4. Widening and Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4)

> First, the byte is converted to an int via widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2),
> and then the resulting int is converted to a char by narrowing primitive conversion
> (§5.1.3).

Note that in Java, most integer calculations are performed using 32-bit integers if the two operands are different types, unless one of them is a `long`. So widening and narrowing conversions are relatively common (although they may be optimized away in the VM).

#### Worked example

Let's show what happens in bits:

```
char a = 'È';       // 0b00000000_10101000 => a

byte b = (byte)a;   // 0b00000000_10101000
                    // -(narrowing)->
                    // 0b1_0101000  => b

char c = (char)b;   // 0b1_0101000
                    // -(widening)->
                    // 0b1_1111111_11111111_11111111_10101000
                    // -(narrowing)->
                    // 0b11111111_10101000 => c

println(.. (int)c); // 0b11111111_10101000
                    // -(widening)->
                    // 0b00000000_00000000_11111111_10101000
```

Here the leftmost sign bit of the signed representations for `byte` and `int` has been separated by a `_`. The reason why the widening or *sign extension* happens is because the byte `0b1_0101000` and the 32 bit integer `0b1_1111111_11111111_11111111_10101000`  both represent the value -56 in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

### Handling the problem

#### Getting the expected result

To get the expected result use `char c = (char) (b & 0xFF)` which first converts the byte value of `b` to the positive integer `200` by using a mask, zeroing the top 24 bits after conversion: `0xFFFFFFC8` becomes `0x000000C8` or the positive number `200` in decimals.

#### Worked example

```
char c = (char) (b & 0xFF); // 0b1_0101000 
                            // -(widening)->
                            // 0b1_1111111_11111111_11111111_10101000
                            // -(AND with 0b0_0000000_00000000_00000000_11111111)->
                            // 0b0_0000000_00000000_00000000_10101000    (narrowing)->
                            // 0b00000000_10101000 => c
```

Note that `0xFF` doesn't represent a byte, it represents an integer; so it is basically the same as `0x000000FF`.

#### Dealing with character-encoding

Above is a direct explanation of what happens during conversion between the `byte`, `int` and `char` primitive types.

If you want to encode/decode characters from bytes, look at classes such as `Charset`, `CharsetEncoder`, `CharsetDecoder` within the [`java.nio.charset` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/package-summary.html). Convenience methods such as `new String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)` or `String#toBytes(Charset charset)` have been defined as well. The required character sets for the Java runtime can be accessed directly as constants through the [`java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) utility class.

Comment: Actually, a Java `char` is not a Unicode *code **point***. It is a UTF-16 *code **unit***. To actually represent an arbitrary Unicode “character” (by which I mean an actual code point), a Java `char` is not good enough: you must use an `int` (effectively giving you UTF-32), which can take up to two chars in legacy UTF-16 notation. That’s why everything has a `codePointAt` API, not just the bad old legacy `charAt` API.

Comment: Why is the `char c = (char) (b & 0xFF)` only using a single byte, when Java chars are supposed to be two bytes?

Comment: @Maarten .. Thanks for the nice catch. Do you know the reason as to why the byte is first widened to an integer and then narrowed to a character? Why not directly widen a byte to a character?

Comment: @RockyInde I've looked at this answer again now it is at 50 upvotes. The answer seems correct, but the answer to this comment did not. It is mainly because *everything* is generally converted to integers in Java. `int` really is the main type in Java; calculations of bytes, shorts and chars are all widened to integer types during such a calculation. This conversion is just a basic but weird example of this.

Comment: @Cory Sorry I never answered that comment. Could you have a look if my rewritten answer does address it sufficiently? Any other comment welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
//Add import statement

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
```

// Change

```
sun.io.ByteToCharConverter.getDefault().getCharacterEncoding() -> Charset.defaultCharset()
```

Comment: Behold! Somebody mentioned the `sun.` package in 2022!!!

Answer (score -2):

`new String(byteArray, Charset.defaultCharset())`

This will convert a byte array to the default charset in java. It may throw exceptions depending on what you supply with the byteArray.

Comment: Wrong. From the documentation: "This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string. The `CharsetDecoder` class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required." So it doesn't throw exceptions as you suggest.

Comment: Doesn't mean it is wrong. It means if you need more control, use CharsetDecoder

Comment: No, it is wrong because you indicate that it may throw exceptions while it doesn't.  Yes, you can use `CharsetDecoder` for more control, but that doesn't make the answer correct. Happy to upvote corrected answers.