# How to add 0 while typecasting to char?

Tags: java, byte

I have a byte **11001000**, when I cast it to char type, it automatically adds 1s to its left so it now becomes **1111111111001000**.

Why is that?
And how to avoid it so I can get a **0000000011001000**?

Comment: Show your code. How you cast to char?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17912706/2073001).

Comment: check the post below

[answered here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912640/byte-and-char-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why there are 1s instead of zeros but a character in Java is 16 bits and thats why there are 16 digits. Maybe you can use the & operator to get rid of those 1s.

11111111111111 & 0000000011001000