# Java Byte Buffer behavior

Tags: java, nio

I was just playing around with Java ByteBuffers and don't understand why the output is not correct.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class TestBuffers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
        byteBuffer.put((byte)'H').put((byte)'e').put((byte)'l').put((byte)'l');
        System.out.println(byteBuffer.asCharBuffer().toString()); // should print "Hell"
    }
}
```

The above program should print "Hell" but it doesn't. but if i give positions in the `put()` call starting from 1 then it works, why?

Comment: it doesn't print anything...if i do `byteBuffer.flip()` then it prints some garbage value.

Comment: Can you post your actual code example? This obviously doesn't compile.

Comment: it must be just the `import` issue. let me add the `java.nio.ByteBuffer` import..

Comment: Your `buf` variable changes name and you're missing a `()` - not a problem, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912640/byte-and-char-conversion-in-java and do `flip()` the buffer.

Comment: corrected..thanks. I typed the code into this window, so used to typing in IDEs :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are *some* problems in your code and in your approach to that task:

1. `put()` methods without the explicit index will update the buffer position. After four put operations the buffer position is 4.
2. `asCharBuffer()` reuses the contents of the original buffer, starting from the current position in the origin buffer, which is 4 and the original buffer has no actual data starting from that position.
3. `flip()` is indeed the proper action before trying to perform `get` operations after a sequence of `put` operations, but:
4. In Java, `char` is a two-byte value, meaning that your original 4-byte buffer will be interpreted as a 2-char buffer, for example the value of the first char will be `( char ) ( ( ( ( byte ) 'H' ) << 8 ) + ( byte ) 'e' )`.

Other that this, the `ByteBuffer` behaves exactly as expected and documented in its javadoc.

An example that fixes the coding problems:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 100 );
byteBuffer
        // explicitly converting each char into 2 bytes
        .put( ( byte ) ( 'H' >>> 8 ) ).put( ( byte ) 'H' ) 
        .put( ( byte ) ( 'e' >>> 8 ) ).put( ( byte ) 'e' )
        .put( ( byte ) ( 'l' >>> 8 ) ).put( ( byte ) 'l' )
        .put( ( byte ) ( 'l' >>> 8 ) ).put( ( byte ) 'l' )
        .put( ( byte ) ( 'o' >>> 8 ) ).put( ( byte ) 'o' );
// flipping the buffer to be able access the current content via get operations
byteBuffer.flip();
// reinterpreting the byte sequence as a char sequence
CharBuffer charBuffer = byteBuffer.asCharBuffer();
System.out.println( charBuffer.toString() );
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that char is 16-bit, and byte is 8-bit. When you cast, you're losing some information. You need to insert two bytes for every char, and then flip the buffer, as per below:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class TestBuffers {
  ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);

  byteBuffer.put((byte) ('H' & 0xFF00)).put((byte) ('H' & 0x00FF)).put((byte) ('E' & 0xFF00))
    .put((byte) ('E' & 0x00FF)).put((byte) ('L' & 0xFF00)).put((byte) ('L' & 0x00FF))
    .put((byte) ('L' & 0xFF00)).put((byte) ('L' & 0x00FF));
  byteBuffer.flip();
  System.out.println(byteBuffer.asCharBuffer().toString()); // should print "Hell"
 }
}
```

Comment: While this code will probably work for ASCII values, you are losing the high values (should be bit-shifting)

Comment: They are actually, but a `char` is always two bytes. This means that when they're converted back to a char, the H byte and the E byte will be combined together to form a character, generating the random garbage he was seeing.

Comment: @Dave True, but I was going for the minimal ASCII example :)

Comment: @EvanKnowles as Oleg's answer is more elaborate, choosing that as the answer. thanks for the help :)